# tablediff example

Tags: ms-access

Hallo experts,

i want to compare the values of two cells in two tables of two mdb. After googling I find that tablediff could perhaps help me in this issue. Could you give me a simple example with this command in case of my problem?

Many thanks in advance,

John

Comment: tablediff is for SQL server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to consider something on these lines:

```
SELECT n1.ID, n1.Field2
FROM New AS n1 
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT ID, Field2 
      FROM New IN 'c:\docs\ltd.mdb') AS n2 
ON n1.ID = n2.ID
WHERE n1.Field2<>n2.Field2
```

There are numerous other possibilities, including using VBA to compare every table in the entire selection of databases.

Access provides a Query Design Window, which is very helpful when learning how to set up queries, but not so useful for the more advanced SQL.

Here are some interesting articles:

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The codes you write here look like SQL, but I know very little about it. Could you tell me: 1. is there any IDE for SQL? 2. do you have any links about the basics of SQL programming?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any free mdb comparator?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but many people recommend Compare 'Em:

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/backendupdate.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. However i cannot get a registration code to activate the application:( This small program looks great, I'm wondering wether it is a VB application, but how could it be implemented? Is there any tutorials/examples for such programming?