# Comparing 2 Access(mdb) files

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, ms-access

We're working on this project and at some point we need to validate data from 2 distinct Access(mdb) files. This validation consists in comparing the entries of this two files based on a column that is the "primary key" to verify if the value the other columns are changed from on file to another.

My coworker wrote some code to import the data from the 2 files into an Oracle table and made the validation using sql joins within a View.

The problem is: the files have too much data, it takes 50+ minutes to load them into the Oracle tables.

Is there a better approach to make this routine? Without importing all the data into the database?

**edit**

Here is the code we're using to import the data (not written by me):

```
protected void InsereDadosTemp()
{
    try
    {
        String vMesAno = ReportParameter.ReportData.Parameters.Item("pMesAnoCompetencia").Value;

        Hashtable hashMesAno = new Hashtable();
        hashMesAno.Add(vMesAno, 1);
        hashMesAno.Add(MesAnterior(vMesAno), 2);

        OleDbConnection objConnOracle = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"].ToString());
        objConnOracle.Open();

        OleDbCommand objCmdPciReport = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM ZBRICAGEM", objConnOracle);
        objCmdPciReport.ExecuteNonQuery();

        foreach (DictionaryEntry obj in hashMesAno)
        {
            string vConnectionString = MontaConnectionString(obj.Key.ToString());

            OleDbConnection objConnAccess = new OleDbConnection(vConnectionString);

            objConnAccess.Open();

            OleDbCommand objCmdAccess = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TEST where EQUIPE NOT IN  ('ONCO', 'DERMA', 'AROMA', 'SOMA', 'IDADE', 'HORMONIO')", objConnAccess);
            OleDbDataReader reader = objCmdAccess.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                objCmdPciReport = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO ZBRICAGEM (ID_BRICK, BRICK, SETOR, EQUIPE, NOME_POOL, BRICKS_UF, BU, ARQUIVO ) Values (" +
                                                              "BRICKS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7)", objConnOracle);
                objCmdPciReport.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Clear();
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":p1", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = reader["BRICK"];
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":p2", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = reader["SETOR"];
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":p3", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = reader["EQUIPE"];
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":p4", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = reader["NOME_POOL"];
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":p5", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = reader["BRICKS_UF"];
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":p6", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = reader["BU"];
                    objCmdPciReport.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":p7", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = Path.GetFileName(objConnAccess.ConnectionString);

                    objCmdPciReport.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            objConnAccess.Close();
        }

        objConnOracle.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro durante a importação de Bricagem: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this validation is part of a report that will be shown to the client. So, he chooses the files he wants to compare, then we insert the data of the files in the database, compare them and present the differences between the files. This files will be copied by the user in a directory and the program will read them. So, unfortunately, we can't work with queries in the Access files.

Comment: Some notes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648565/tablediff-example/4649313#4649313 I wrote some code at one stage that compares all tables with a relevant primary key.

Comment: How are you loading the access data into oracle?  Perhaps some performance tuning of that procedure will help.

Comment: I've added the code we're using to import the data.

Answer (score 0):

- Open one .mdb in access
- Attach the table in the other database to the opened one (right click the Tables pane, pick 'link tables' or do it [programmatically](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/link-tables-macro.html))
- In the queries tab, make a new query to do the compare - should be similar to what you did in oracle. You may be able to switch to SQL view and paste the same code.

If this is very slow, try to copy both files to the same hard drive. But you probably won't have to if you're not updating. You can also look into doing the queries in read-only mode somehow (MSA won't try to lock the .mdb's, slower over the network). Access may not be as smart as Oracle, but, it's going to be decent with its own data format and a simple join. And it is going to blow the doors off of importing into oracle.

#### edit

In reply to the comment:

*Thanks @FastAl, but we can't manipulate the Access files "by hand", they will be copied to a directory of the website by the user and we're the only way we are going to interact with them is via C# code*

It may be still possible to leverage this method. Querying linked tables would be the speed key.

- Standardize on path/filenames for the 2 access DBs you will be copying. Either write them directly as these names from the web uploading code, or if the user is copying via network share, just tell them to name them properly.
- Make a 3rd .mdb that attaches to the tables in copies of the databases you've placed in the standardized name/locations.
- Open it in you c# program; see http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007 or http://www.connectionstrings.com/access.
- Run the query from c# (you could have it in the 3rd .mdb via MSAccess, too, and just open the query as a table name).

Make sure you properly close the 3rd MDB from the program; otherwise you won't be able to overwrite the 2 other DBs with new ones, they'll be in-use.

It's also possible to programatically link tables in access from c# - I did it long ago and have forgotten how, though. You can also link them to oracle/SQL; this may require doing process.execute /.Waitforexit and just running scripts in those dbms' to handle it, though. Hacks galore. I can't see their 'link to access' drivers being faster than access; at best they probalby just use the 'jet engine' dll (guess).

Comment: Thanks @FastAl, but we can't manipulate the Access files "by hand", they will be copied to a directory of the website by the user and we're the only way we are going to interact with them is via C# code.